# The added to the solution project which function is referenced in Web.config for "preCondition" is required to have a "Main" method

Tags: c#, dll, reference, web-config

I have a project in solution whose `Web.config` file has a precondition set to handle errors:

```
<modules>
  <add name="ErrorModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="TestProject.MyModule.ErrorHandler"/>
</modules>
```

I added `TestProject` to a solution. And when running the solution, I'm getting the error that "Program does not contain a static `Main` method suitable for an entry"

I read that I would have to compile the project into a `dll`.
However, I don't see that this project was somehow referencing that `dll` before.

The project didn't need to use `Main` method before neither.
Also, when compiling that project into `dll`, I'm getting the same error regarding the `Main` method.

What is the solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

My project file's `OutputType` was set to `exe` instead of `Library`